# c# How to know certain RSS has blank

Tags: c#, arraylist, rss

I managed to search news with RSS

Then, able to select topic from a listbox and display news in a richTextBox.

But there are some topics with empty news.

How can I remove the unwanted topics.

I using ArrayList to store.

```
ArrayList liberal = new ArrayList();

//searching news by keyword

 string searchTerm = searchTextBox.Text;

 liberalRss = getRssData(liberal, searchTerm);

 for (int i = 0; i < liberalRss.GetLength(0); i++){

     if (liberalRss[i, 0] != null)

     {

          liberalListBox.Items.Add(liberalRss[i, 0]);

     }

 }
```

I tried remove in for loop by this >>> `liberalRss[i, 0] maybe liberalRss[i, 0].remove`

but stil cannot work

Thanks

Comment: try **string.Empty** instead of **null**

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda stil cannot make it
how should i use string.Empty

Comment: anyone have idea to help to remove unwanted news topic?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < liberalRss.GetLength(0); i++){

     if (liberalRss[i, 0] != **string.Empty**)

     {

          liberalListBox.Items.Add(liberalRss[i, 0]);

     }

 }` this should solve the problem.

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda so sorry for late replied... I solved it....thanks a lot!

Comment: have you solved using string.Empty ?